# Combining two scripts

Tags: autohotkey

I have a few simple autofire scripts that I use in my game which I want to merge into a single script.

I tried a few things but couldn't make it work... The scripts are:

```
~$*[::
Loop                
{
GetKeyState, var, [, P
If var = U
    Break
Send {q}
sleep 200
}
```

The other 3 are the same i just change the `Send {key}`. So in other words, when I hold down the `[` key , I want `q`,`w`,`e`, and `Lmouseclick` to be clicked.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you looking to have "[" send q, w, e, and LM in sequence? Have the option of what key to send? Or just have another key send q, a different one send w, etc.?

Comment: I figured it out myself ... i wanted ] to trigger all 4 buttons at once ... i just used the send command 4 times in same script and workd ...

Comment: Mark it answered, even if you answered it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this one correctly, you could simply do the following:

```
[::
{
    Send, q
}
return

]::
{
    Send, qwe
    MouseClick, left
}
return
```